# Where to place web.xml outside WAR file for secure redirect?

Tags: redirects, https, tomcat

I am running Tomcat 7 and am deploying a bunch of applications delivered to me by a third party as WAR files.

I'd like to force **some** of those apps to always use SSL. (All the "SSL" apps are in one service; other apps outside this discussion are in another service.)

I've figured out how to use *conf\web.xml* to redirect apps from HTTP to HTTPS, but that applies to all applications hosted by Tomcat. I've also figured out how to put *web.xml* in an unpacked app's *web-inf* directory; that does the trick for that specific app, but runs the risk of being overwritten if our vendor gives us a new war file to deploy.

I've also tried placing the *web.xml* file in various places under *conf\service\host*, or under *appbase*, but none seem to work.

Is it possible to redirect some apps to SSL without forcing all apps to redirect, or to put the *web.xml file* inside the extracted WAR file?

Here's my *server.xml*:

```
<Service name="secure">
    <Connector port="80" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8" enableLookups="false" compression="on"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
        compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,application/json,text/css"/>
    <Connector port="443"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8" enableLookups="false" compression="on"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
        compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,application/json,text/css"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
        keystoreFile="..." keystorePass="..." keystoreType="PKCS12" 
        truststoreFile="..." truststorePass="..." truststoreType="JKS"
        clientAuth="false" 
        ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"/>
    <Engine name="secure" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
            resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="false" 
            autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="mutual-secure">
    ...
</Service>
```

The content of the *web.xml* files I'm playing with is:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="true">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All applications</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <description>Redirect all requests to HTTPS</description>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

(For *conf\web.xml* the security-constraint is added just before the end of the existing file, rather than create a new file.)

My *webapps* directory (currently) contains only the WAR files.

Comment: i dont know how but i think its solveable with symblic links :/

Comment: Good question. But this is more of a server question that is better suited for Server Fault. http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of additional locations where you can have `web.xml` files for Tomcat.

One thing that I do is run Tomcat as a secondary server on port 8080 behind Apache.  I use mod_proxy to reverse proxy domains from Apache port 80 to Tomcat port 8080.   This way I can put all the SSL onto Apache and configure Apache for the non-SSL redirects using virtual hosts.  That way the logic for the SSL is configured separately and outside the control of the webapps.